# jQuery version 1.3.2 is not working in Firefox

Tags: jquery

I am trying to do a simple jQuery tutorial, but it won't work.

I have copied and pasted the jquery filename: jquery-1.3.2

I can't see what is wrong? I am using Firefox.

```js
$(function() {
  $('a').click(function() {
    $('#box').fadeOut();
  });
});
```

```css
#box {
  background: red;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box"></div>
<a href="#">Click Me</a>
```

Comment: Tell us what happens. Nothing? Errors from the browser? Something unexpected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to be so careful with where you put the different parts of the code for it to work.

Have a look at this code which worked for me.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <title>Fade Out Red Box</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <style type="text/css">
  #box
  {
    background: red;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
  }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="box"></div>
  <a href="#">Click me</a>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("a").click(function() {
        $("#box").fadeOut("slow");
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hmmm that is interesting, you have the script tags in the body of the doc. Thanks it works.

Comment: Where you put your SCRIPT tags is up to you. In my code you can put them in the HEAD and it will still work. It just dictates when you start seeing your page. Everything in the HEAD is loaded before the page starts to draw. 

In your code you also tried to link to an external file in the SCRIPT tag *and* provide some code which isn't possible.

Answer (score 15):

Put your click event code in different script block.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('a').click(function() {
                    $('#box').fadeOut();
            });
    }); 
    </script>
```

The error you committed remembers me of [Degrading Script Tags](http://ejohn.org/blog/degrading-script-tags/)

> Script tags that reference external resources (via the src attribute) are no longer able to execute script embedded within the tag itself.

Answer (score 9):

First, make sure you have the `jquery-1.3.2.js` in your directory.

Then, change your script tags:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
            $('a').click(function() {
                    $('#box').fadeOut();
            });
    });
</script>
```